# CameraX - prevent closing torch or flash after imageCapture.takePicture

Tags: android, android-camerax

I am developing an app where I need to keep the torch on as long as the camera is working, and meanwhile, I also have to take photos without closing the torch off. I need this functionality for a better user experience.

But every time I take a photo the torch is gets off, my question is that how can I prevent this from happening?

```kotlin
class CameraFragment : Fragment()  {
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService
    
    private var cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider? = null
    private var preview: Preview? = null
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    private var imageAnalysis: ImageAnalysis? = null
    private var camera: Camera? = null

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(),
                REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS,
                REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS
            )
        }
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            bindCameraUseCases()
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()))
    }

    private fun bindCameraUseCases() {

        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
            .build()

        val rotation = binding.viewFinder.display.rotation

        preview = Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetRotation(rotation)
            .build()

        imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
            .setTargetRotation(rotation)
            .setCaptureMode(CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)
            .build()

        imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setTargetRotation(rotation)
            .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
            .setOutputImageFormat(ImageAnalysis.OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_RGBA_8888)
            .build()

        imageAnalysis?.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor) {
            // Some analysis
        }

        cameraProvider?.unbindAll()

        try {
            camera = cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(
                this@CameraFragment,
                cameraSelector,
                preview,
                imageCapture,
                imageAnalysis
            )

            // OPEN FLASH
            openFlash()

            preview?.setSurfaceProvider(binding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
        } catch(exc: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
        }
    }

    private fun takePhoto() {
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

        imageCapture.takePicture(cameraExecutor, object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
            override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
                super.onCaptureSuccess(image)
                // image process
            }

            override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                super.onError(exception)
                println("ERROR")
            }
        })
    }

    private fun openFlash() {
        if (camera?.cameraInfo?.hasFlashUnit() == true) {
            camera?.cameraControl?.enableTorch(true)
        }
    }

    private fun closeFlash() {
        if (camera?.cameraInfo?.hasFlashUnit() == true) {
            camera?.cameraControl?.enableTorch(false)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        openFlash()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        closeFlash()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "Camera"
        //  private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10

        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = mutableListOf (
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
        ).toTypedArray()
    }
}
```

Comment: Taking picture should not turn off the torch. If you have a minimal reproducible example, I can take a look.

Comment: Maybe it was the problem with the xiomi device but I ended up using camera2 for my project. That was exactly the code I used for cameraX. I noticed even in camera2 flash was getting off but I managed to solve that. @Xi张熹

Answer (score 0):

You should use **setFlashMode(FLASH_MODE_ON)** to imageCapture builder.

```
imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
        .setTargetRotation(rotation)
        .setFlashMode(FLASH_MODE_ON)
        .setCaptureMode(CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)
        .build()
```

Comment: I have tried already this

Comment: As I checked its working for me. Can you share more details on this issues?